# Is this probabilty calculation correct?(Based on Town of Salem but you don't need to know the game)

Tags: probability

I'll just give you the four rules that matter in this problem and explain my thought process and the other opinion.

Rule #1: 15 players are playing a game.

Rule #2: One player (J) can secretly select a player (not themselves).

Rule #3: A different player (K) can then secretly select a player (not themselves) and kill them.

Rule #4: If J selects K, then K will be given no choice and will kill J.

Clarification: J and K can select the same person.

It is then revealed that K killed J. What is the probability that J had selected K?

Let Q be the required probability.

I will attempt to calculate the probability that J did NOT select K given that K killed J.

Let's call A the event {J does NOT select K} and B the event {K kills J}.

We're trying to calculate P(A/B), which is equal to P(AB)/P(B). Clarification: AB means A∩B.

P(Β) first. B can happen if J selects K (1/14), or K selects J (1/14), minus the intersection (1/196). Thus, P(B)=2/14-1/196=27/196.

AB now. The probability that K selects J (1/14), minus P{K selects J AND J selects K} (1/196). So, P(AB)=13/196.

Thus, P(A/B)=0.481481... or about 48%. And Q=0.52. Almost.

Some people, however, argued that since we know J died to K, the sample space only includes the events {K killed J}, of which there are 14, and only 1 of those also includes J selecting K, thus Q=1/14. Part of the argument is that P(B)=1, since we know that K killed J.

I am not sure wether we are looking for dependent probability or intersection. The problem, however, is perfectly defined. If it is revealed that K killed J, what are the odds of J having selected K?

EDIT: Another clarification: While, yes, both J and K do not have to select another player, we assume that both did (although K will kill J if he is selected, even if he doesn't want to kill anyone).

I was also a bit vague about what J does when he selects another player because it is irrelevant. If you must know, during the day he selects the player he wants to interrogate that night, and in all nights except the first one (which this problem examines), kill them if he so wants. There are exceptions, but this is the general rule.

Comment: 'Rule #2: One player (J) can secretly select a player (not themselves).' and what happens then exactly?  Do they intend to kill them?  What if they don't select anyone?  That part is totally unclear.  The whole thing is pretty vague

Comment: the word 'can' appears over and over.  Maybe he 'can' select someone, but it is very unlikely, or maybe it is the rules of the game so he has to do that.  In any case the link between selecting someone and dying if they select you is not really clear, is it possible that anyone could kill anyone else?  Maybe players take turns to select a player and if there is a collision where J selected K then K selected J, then J dies to K?  Why it would have a probability is not clear - maybe you could explain with a 3 player game, A,B,C?

Comment: You are correct that it is unlear with the word "can". I'll edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Here is another way of looking at this question.
Let $A$ be the event that J selects K, and $B$ be the event that K kills J. We want to find $P(A|B)$. Using Bayes rule
$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$.

Let's calculate each one individually.
$$P(A) = 1/14$$
$$P(B|A) = 1, \text{by definition}$$
$$P(B) = P(B|A)P(A) + P(B|A^c)P(A^c), \text{by the law of total probability}$$
$$P(B) = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{14} + \frac{1}{14}\cdot\frac{13}{14}$$

so $P(A|B) = 14/27$.

Answer (score 0):

Nice math.  I was too lazy to study bayesian probability sufficiently to formulate this on my own, so I simply wrote a short Java program to simulate the situation 5 million times and then measured the average result.  My "Q" result came out to about 51.6%, which seems consistent with your math.